# NSTextView monitor caret position change

Tags: macos, cocoa, key-value-observing, nstextfield, nstextview

How can i get a callback on the caret position change for a NSTextView?

I tried KVO

```
[textView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedRange" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

But i don't get the callback when i move with arrow keys, or mouse... probably because the range is a struct, which gets its members modified (i get only callback when the text changes)

**But how to monitor a caret position change?**

Comment: Hey man did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version:

```
public func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ notification: Notification) {
   guard let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView,
         let string = textView.textStorage?.string else {
      return
   }

   if let nsRange = textView.selectedRanges.first as? NSRange,
      let range = Range(nsRange, in: string) {
      print(nsRange)
      print(range.lowerBound.encodedOffset, range.upperBound.encodedOffset)
   }
}
```